# Error importing tensorflow in Python 3 on Ubuntu 16.04 SyntaxError: l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

1. I have **python 3.5** installed on my Linux Mint (**Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial**)
2. I also had installed **protobuf** installed using `pip3 install protobuf`
3. I installed **tensorflow** using `pip3 install tensorflow`

Then I tried to import tensorflow in python 3 it failed with error presented below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdullah/face_recognition/tensorflow_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator_lib as estimator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs import inputs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/inputs.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.numpy_io import numpy_input_fn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.inputs.queues import feeding_functions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_functions.py", line 40, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 361, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Consulting through many questions posted on SO and other forums, I tried uninstalling **protobuf** then I encountered following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdullah/face_recognition/tensorflow_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
```

At the moment I'm just a beginner for all of this. I don't why protobuf is required why do all this hassle? I just wanted to get tensorflow installed on my system and try to learn something.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. The problem I think is this is using pandas from system(apt-get) repository which is not compatible with other libraries. Updating `pandas` do the trick.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Also in your case, if only doing above fails, you can also try to reinstall `tensorflow` and `protobuf` with upgrade option.

```
pip3 install --upgrade protobuf
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I just installed TensorFlow on my system today (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) using VirtualEnv.

Did you run`$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev` 

If so, then try `$ pip3 install -upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl`

Worst comes to worse, you could simply uninstall TensorFlow using `$ sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow` and then try reinstalling to see if it corrects any errors.

Comment: Yes I had installed python3-pip and python3-dev
I also tried ```pip3 install -upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl``` 
at first it says ```no such option: -u```
I retried by remove "-" before "-upgrade", then is said 
```Collecting upgrade
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for upgrade```
I tried ```pip3 install <URL>``` then it said ```requirements already satisfied```
I also tried uninstalling and re-installing tensorflow bt made no use